# hibernate interceptor in flush dirty method previous state.issue

Tags: hibernate, interceptor

I am using spring MVC +hibernate+hibernate interceptor. When I am invoking update method of hibernate onflush dirty methd is calling in interceptor . I am getting null values is previous state.I am stuck in these issue since 2 days.
If any body hd face this type of issue and got the solution then please suggest some solutions for the same
.

Regards 
Capil